# Comparing 2 independent counts of the same data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, count-data, agreement-statistics

I am looking for an appropriate statistical method to test my hypothesis that there is no significant difference between counts conducted by 2 individuals of the same data.

The data is as follows:

I have videos of fish migrating up a river, and 2 different people counting the videos.

I have 960 videos, so each video is counted once by each person.

I am unsure what type of statistical test will evaluate the difference between counters, as this is ultimately what I am testing: How well do counters agree with one another, in other words, is one counter significantly different than the other counter when presented with the same data.

If anyone could suggest the appropriate statistical test that would be awesome.

Comment: Do you have counts for each of the 960 videos, or just the totals over all of the videos? If you have the raw counts, look at the distribution of the differences. Test whether the mean difference is zero.

Comment: The question (where it is fish that is counted and not the videos) has also been answered elsewhere: http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/53557-A-simple-question-Looking-to-compare-counts-conducted-by-2-counters-of-the-same-data

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about **agreement**, which has its own tag on this site [agreement-statistics](/questions/tagged/agreement-statistics). An earlier question similar to yours is

- [Testing for similarity on count data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146108/testing-for-similarity-on-count-data), also
- [What is the proper inter-rater reliability analysis for continuous count data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221708/what-is-the-proper-inter-rater-reliability-analysis-for-continuous-count-data)