# Testing for similarity on count data

Tags: chi-squared-test, count-data, fishers-exact-test, agreement-statistics

Is there a statistical test tat can test for similarity between two data sets on a count data?

The only test I can think of doing on a count data is chi squared test and fisher exact test and both test for differences between the two data sets.

I don't think I can use the P value for similarity as 1 - (p value of difference), can I ?

My actual data is as follows:

[image]         [image]

Alterrnatively the data can be arranged in the table below:

[image]

Comment: What's a 'p-value for similarity'? What test statistic? What's the null, and what's the alternative?

Comment: Null Hypothesis: treatment A bears no similarity to treatment b. Response yes in treatment A can equally be response yes or response no in treatment b.

Comment: Aletrnative hypothesis: Response in treatment A is similiar to response in treatment b. so response Yes in treatment A is likely to be response yes in treatment B.

Comment: I have done fishers exact test on treatment a and treatment b and the P value I got was 1. This is representing that there is no difference between the two treatments. However, It is not valid for me to say that as the P value is 1 the two treatments are similiar. Therefore I am trying to establish if there is a statistical test that I can use on a count data that measures for similarity rather than differences.

Comment: To do a hypothesis test you need to work out the probability of rejection when $H_0$ is true (or more generally, the largest probability for composite hypotheses). How are you going to do that?

Comment: alpha value has to be below 0.05 and beta value 0.2. these are the standards we use in our field. is that what you are asking?

Comment: No, sorry, it isn't. How are you going to *get* an alpha of 0.05 or lower? What rejection rule can achieve it?

Comment: I think the OP is asking for a null hypothesis of data having a difference, and alternate of they being the same..something along the lines of equivalence testing if I am not wrong? but for count data, and not population distributions.

Comment: Can you post an example of your data? What are your variables? Do you have a contingency table?

Comment: Rover eye is right. I have edited my post and added the tables with my actual data gung. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, now what do you mean by similarity in this context? For instance, one situation is where you have 2 doctors say who they think will recover & you wonder if they select the same patients, but that doesn't seem to apply in your case, as you have plants vs genes, not dr1 vs dr2.

Comment: it’s more like they have the same patients, and you are wondering if the 2 doctors think they will recover. or does one doctor say they will recover and the other does not? there is similarity if both the doctors say the patients will recover. There is difference if one doctor says the patients will recover and the other says they will not.

Comment: In my case I am asking if the same genes in two different plants (A and B) respond similarly. It is similar if out of 15 genes upregulated (increased) in plant A, 13 (same) genes are also upregulated in plant B. if out of 10 genes downregulated (decreased) in plant A, 8 are also downregulated in plant B.

Comment: Gung, I have arranged the table in Dr1 Vs Dr 2 format so that the contingency table shows plant A Vs Plant B. I am testing if the same genes are similarly upregulated or similarly downregulated in plant A and B.

Comment: For me to be notified that you left a comment, you need to ping me like so: @afreensahiri. (You are always notified, because this is your Q.) Your 2nd table is the correct format here; the 1st table is incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question you are asking is about [agreement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability).  You may want to check out John Uebersax's [website](http://john-uebersax.com/stat/agree.htm) on agreement.  You need to think in terms of the format of your second contingency table, because your data are matched in the sense that the observations are of the same genes.  The test you want is [Cohen's kappa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa).  In R, it could be done like this:

```r
library(irr)                         # you need to use this package
dat = matrix(c(rep(c("u", "d"), 4),  # here I input your data
               rep(c("d", "u"), 2),
               rep(c("d", "d"), 9) ), ncol=2, byrow=T)
dat
#       [,1] [,2]
#  [1,] "u"  "d" 
#  [2,] "u"  "d" 
#  [3,] "u"  "d" 
#  [4,] "u"  "d" 
#  [5,] "d"  "u" 
#  [6,] "d"  "u" 
#  [7,] "d"  "d" 
#  [8,] "d"  "d" 
#  [9,] "d"  "d" 
# [10,] "d"  "d" 
# [11,] "d"  "d" 
# [12,] "d"  "d" 
# [13,] "d"  "d" 
# [14,] "d"  "d" 
# [15,] "d"  "d" 
kappa2(dat)  # this is the test, you have (non-significant) disagreement
#  Cohen's Kappa for 2 Raters (Weights: unweighted)
# 
#  Subjects = 15 
#    Raters = 2 
#     Kappa = -0.216 
#         z = -0.916 
#   p-value = 0.36
```

Comment: You're welcome, @afreensahiri.